# Are we allowed to use conditional expression inside the let-in expression in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples

```
kinerja :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
kinerja j m d =
    let seconds = j*3600 + m*60 + d
    in 
        let 
            durasi x = abs (seconds - 17*3600 + m*30)
        in
            let js = durasi `div` 3600
                ms = (durasi `div` 60) `mod` 60
                ds = durasi `mod` 60
            in
                if j <= 17 && m < 30 then (js,ms,ds,1)
                else if j == 17 && m == 30 then (js,ms,ds,0)
                else (js,ms,ds,(-1))
```

I'm getting error with these code. I'm trying to have tuple output. The element js, ms, and ds are the gap between the clock input and 17.30. The problem is on the element js, ms, and ds. Is there any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: `durasi` is defined as a function not an `Int`. Remove the `x` in its definition

Comment: @Vikstapolis Ah, I see. I get it now, thank you so much!

Comment: Note that you can put all the equations in the same `let`: even if some equations refer to the variables defined by other equations, that will still work. There is no need to nest `let`s as you do.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i always define Functions explicitly and i dont trust the implicit ones. Doing that and removing the "x" from durasi, which didnt make any sense to me, it works now:

```hs
kinerja :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
kinerja j m d =
    let seconds :: Int
        seconds = j*3600 + m*60 + d
    in 
        let durasi :: Int
            durasi = abs (seconds - 17*3600 + m*30)
        in
            let js :: Int
                js = durasi `div` 3600
                ms :: Int
                ms = (durasi `div` 60) `mod` 60
                ds :: Int
                ds = durasi `mod` 60
            in
                if j <= 17 && m < 30 then (durasi `div` 3600 ,ms,ds,1)
                else if j == 17 && m == 30 then (js,ms,ds,0)
                else (js,ms,ds,-1)

kinerja2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int, Int, Int)
kinerja2 j m d 
    | j <= 17 && m < 30 = (durasi `div` 3600 ,ms,ds,1)
    | j == 17 && m == 30 = (js,ms,ds,0)
    | otherwise =  (js,ms,ds, -1)
    where
        seconds :: Int
        seconds = j*3600 + m*60 + d
        durasi :: Int
        durasi = abs (seconds - 17*3600 + m*30)
        js :: Int
        js = durasi `div` 3600
        ms :: Int
        ms = (durasi `div` 60) `mod` 60
        ds :: Int
        ds = durasi `mod` 60
```